# changing TOC font family / removing chapter headings in 'report' document class?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters

I'm new to LaTeX, so please bear with me for a bit if the description of my problem seems incoherent :)

I've started to write my thesis using the `report` document class, but I've soon found out that it insists on prepending a redundant `Chapter n` to any chapter I begin. I've tried to work around this by declaring my chapters as `\chapter*{Sneaky chapter}`, but this causes them to be omitted from the TOC.

I've switched to the `scrreprt` document class since then, and it does pretty much what I wanted from it regarding the chapter headings, aside from the unsightly sans-serif font it insists on using. So, I've restyled my chapter headings (and sections, and so on and so forth) using the following:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

Again, this does exactly what it says on the tin, but the headings in the TOC remain in the default sans-serif font.

So, in a nutshell, it would be pretty awesome if the chapter headings were set using the default serif font, and the unneeded `Chapter n` gotten rid of. There are no doubt dozens of possible ways to achieve this, I'm sure, but my LaTeX-fu is sadly not up to the task yet.

Comment: I did a bit of mixing and matching yesterday, and it seems that using `\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}` in combination with `report` document class leaves me with the standard serif font and suppresses the `Chapter n` headings. This is probably just a side effect, but it seems to work.

I'm just posting it here for the sake of completeness, for people who potentially want to use the `report` document class, but I'll personally go with Thorsten's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can all be done with internal features of [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

For details see the user guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{%
  \normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\end{document}
```